# When combining columns with same names, how to control appended identifier?

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I want to select some columns from two dataframes and combine them; however, they have the same names. No problem:

```
mtcars_1 = mtcars
mtcars_2 = mtcars

mt_combined = data.frame(mtcars_1[, 1:3], mtcars_2[, 2:3])
```

Now, the names of columns that exist in both dataframes are `disp.1` and so on. What I would like is to be able to control the appended string such that I get something akin to `disp.mtcars_2`, or even better `disp.(somevariabledefinedinfunction)`.

How can I achieve this?

Please note in this example obviously `mtcars_1` and `_2` are the same, but there could be examples where this is not the case i.e. I have two dataframes with the same number of observations but from different days, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you name data.frame parameters in `data.frame`, it will prepend the name, e.g.

```r
head(data.frame(df1 = mtcars[, 1:3], df2 = mtcars[, 2:3]))
#>                   df1.mpg df1.cyl df1.disp df2.cyl df2.disp
#> Mazda RX4            21.0       6      160       6      160
#> Mazda RX4 Wag        21.0       6      160       6      160
#> Datsun 710           22.8       4      108       4      108
#> Hornet 4 Drive       21.4       6      258       6      258
#> Hornet Sportabout    18.7       8      360       8      360
#> Valiant              18.1       6      225       6      225
```

For finer control, set the column names directly beforehand.

Comment: Another great answer, thanks. For my purposes I think this solution is even better than setnames, if only for the readability and brevity it offers. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `setNames` with `paste`

```
mt_combined <- data.frame(mtcars[,1:3],  setNames(mtcars_2[,2:3], 
                          paste0(names(mtcars)[2:3], ".mtcars_2")))
```

---

We can also create a function that makes use of `quosures` from the devel version of `dplyr` (soon to be released `0.6.0`

```
 f1 <- function(dat1, dat2, colInd1, colInd2){
    str1 <- quo_name(enquo(dat2))
    newN <- paste0(names(dat2)[colInd2], ".",str1)
    names(dat2)[colInd2] <- newN
    dat1 %>%
          select(colInd1) %>%
          bind_cols(., select(dat2, colInd2))

 }

 head(f1(mtcars_1, mtcars_2, 1:3, 2:3), 2)
 #    mpg cyl disp cyl.mtcars_2 disp.mtcars_2
 #1  21   6  160            6           160
 #2  21   6  160            6           160
```

Here, the `enquo` takes the input argument and do similar job as `substitute` from `base R` to convert it to `quosure`, the `quo_name` convert it to string to be used in the `paste`

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly